# Installing a .run file in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, sdk

I am using Linux Mint 19. I am working on the [TI 15.4 Stack - Linux Gateway Project Zero](http://dev.ti.com/tirex/content/simplelink_academy_cc13x0sdk_1_12_01_16/modules/154-stack_03_linux_project_0/154-stack_03_linux_project_0.html). I am on task 3, *Install the TI-15.4 Stack Linux Gateway SDK*.

I installed this file by following the link:

```
ti154stack_linux_x64_2_08_00_04.run
```

and through the Linux terminal I navigated to the folder where the above file is installed, and I put the following commands in the terminal as stated per the instructions:

```
chmod +x ti15.4stack_linux_x64_2_08_00_04.run ./ti15.4stack_linux_x64_2_08_00_04.run
```

and this is what I got :

```
$ chmod +x ti15.4stack_linux_x64_2_08_00_04.run ./ti15.4stack_linux_x64_2_08_00_04.run
chmod: cannot access 'ti15.4stack_linux_x64_2_08_00_04.run': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access './ti15.4stack_linux_x64_2_08_00_04.run': No such file or directory
```

I copied the file name it is ti154stack_linux_x64_2_08_00_04.run .
I would appreciate it if you can write them in 2 seperate commands if that is how you think they need to be entered. Here is what I get after performing ls

[image: ls -Al command]

Comment: `ti154stack_linux_x64_2_08_00_04.run` and `ti15.4stack_linux_x64_2_08_00_04.run` are different. `chmod +x <X> ./<Y>` should probably be two different commands/lines. Perform an `ls -Al` and post your results.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @jww , I just edited the question to show the result of ls - al. I don't understand what you mean by those 2 files are different. Did I make a typo by writing the 2 file names differently?

Comment: Ok now I know what you are talking about , I there was a mismatch due to the way it is spelled in the guide and what it installed as. I don't think it should be allowed to use a . in the filename over than for the file extension. Thanks a lot I performed ls -Al again and It is now showing a .run file installed

Comment: Assuming the file is downloaded somewhere in you `$HOME` directory... `find $HOME -name '*.run'`

Comment: It looks like it has installed. Is there a way I could check if it got installed and where it got installed? There is a file that I am going to need from it. Thanks